# Using "Current Month" in a tuple in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: tuples, mdx, cognos

I have an issue where I want to use "Current Month" calculated from a timestamp. In Report Studio I have a List there I want to use a data item with a tuple with two other members and a measure.

When I try the below code I get values:

```
tuple(
    currentMember ([Member1]),
    currentMember ([Member2]),
    [Time].[Calendar].[Month]->:[M12].[[Time]].[Calendar]].[Month]].&[201504]]],    
    [Measure]
)
```

But when I replace the Time-member with:

```
#'[Time].[Calendar].[Month]->:[M12].[[Time]].[Calendar]].[Month]].&[' + timestampMask(_add_days($current_timestamp, -1),'yyyymm') + ']]]'#
```

...it is just empty. I get no errors.

If I test this line in another data item I will get Current Month correct and I have also checked that the string actually is exactly the same as I wrote above.

I even replaced the timestampmask with a string "201504" and that works as well:

```
#'[Time].[Calendar].[Month]->:[M12].[[Time]].[Calendar]].[Month]].&[' + '201504' + ']]]'#
```

Is it just impossible to use timestamp with a tuple? Or can this be solved in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the macro in another Data Item and then reference that new DI from your tuple.

Comment: I did use another DI from the beginning but that didn't work so I tried to paste it directly into the "Current Month" DI but no difference...

Answer (score 0):

(not a solution but will maybe help)

Create a custom measure that's definition is as follows:

`timestampMask(_add_days($current_timestamp, -1),'yyyymm')`

Add this new measure to the columns of a query.
Does it return the values you expect? e.g.`'201504'`

Comment: It does return "2015 Apr" when I run the report but I can't use it in the tuple function, and without that I can't get the value of intersection that I want.

Comment: in pure `mdx` the functions `strToSet` and `strToMember` are used in these sort of situation. In terms of cognos I'm not sure